# Не отображается вертикальное меню

Tags: html, вёрстка, шаблоны, меню

У меня такая проблема, я пытаюсь добавить вертикальное всплывающее меню к шаблону, но меню не хочет отображаться, оно будето скрыто под другими слоями кода и я не могу понять в чем дело. Вот пример, там в хедере мои потуги заставить меню отображаться https://codepen.io/mctracker/pen/peWBpJ

```
.menu_menu {position: relative !important;}
.submenu_menu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 100%;        
    display: none;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;  
    z-index: 1;      

}
.menu_menu:hover .submenu_menu {
    display: block;

}
```

. Возможно я делаю что-то не так, с версткой я на Вы, потому что в основном пишу на php. Буду благодарен за любое пояснение по данному вопросу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2017/03/16/0001/1889/128865/65/913c87aede.jpg]

1. У Вас не валидная вёрстка. Рядом с `li` лежит `ul` - это не правильно.
2. Вы планируете наводить на `.menu_menu` и показывать `.submenu_menu`. Так не сработает.
   `.submenu_menu` должен находиться внутри `.menu_menu`, чтобы сработал стиль 
   `.menu_menu:hover .submenu_menu`.

Поправьте вёрстку вот так:

```
<li class="menu_menu">
   <a href="#">
     <i class="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Statistics</span>
   </a>

   <ul class="submenu_menu">
     <li><a href="#">подменю</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">подменю</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">подменю</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">подменю</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

[Исправленная песочница](https://codepen.io/YozhEzhi/pen/xqXNGW).

Comment: Спасибо, верно, поменял как вы указали, но меню все равно по наведению не отображается.

Comment: Я проверял должно работать. Поделитесь правленным кодпеном - посмотрим вместе.

Comment: Вот, все тот же линк но с испавлением https://codepen.io/mctracker/pen/peWBpJ

Comment: Обновил ответ. Я в песочнице изменил `.submenu_menu {display: none; top: 0;}`. Внимательно посмотрите на выпадающее меню: у вас там белый текст. Наведите на пункты выпадающего меню - они изменят цвет, как было задумано.

Comment: Да, вижу, выводятся. Но почему они полностью белые кроме границы?

Comment: Потому, что у подменю нет фона. Подменю не белое, а прозрачное, по сути. Допишите в `.submenu_menu` { background: #0e1a35;}. И если проблема решена - отметьте мой ответ.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55471/discussion-between-alex-petrov-and-yozhezhi).